# Where does the repl put all the dynamically compiled class files?

Tags: clojure

If I type in the repl:

(fn []), it gives me back an anonymous function that is an instantiation of a generated class. Where can I find the byte representation of the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in memory. Even in non-REPL code (i.e. in a .clj file) you probably will never see the .class file; it'll just compile to bytecode and run it when necessary.

This is an excerpt from [Michal Marczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/232707/michal-marczyk)'s excellent [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107299/how-do-clojure-programs-compilers-interpreters-actually-work#comment3194881_3107585) about .clj files:

> Normally no actual .class files are produced, though you can ask for
>   them if you want (see (doc compile) and (doc *compile-files*)).
>   There's no reason to worry about this most of the time. Note that this
>   mode of operation is not particular to Clojure at all; Python does the
>   same thing, compiling .py files to Python bytecode and then running
>   it.

According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/j__YEO5t7eI), even manually requested compilation (via [gen-class](http://clojure.org/compilation)) isn't possible from the REPL, because `gen-class` looks for a `.clj` file to turn into a `.class` file.

P.s. To dump an object to a file (which I know isn't exactly what you're after) you can check out [this site](http://nakkaya.com/2009/11/01/clojure-persistence-for-java-programmers/), which just uses `clojure.core/prn` to serialise a class and then a java.io.FileWriter to dump it to a file.

Comment: Is there a way to access the bytes? It doesn't have to be in a file. I just want the literal byte representation somehow

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Instrumentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) to register a transformer to be called whenever a class is loaded or (re)defined. The [Transformer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html) receives the class name and bytes in class file format.